# TinyMCE issue: textarea not updated even with TriggerSave()

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE in a form where I use ajax to submit the form. I've been struggling for the last 4 hours to figure out what is going wrong but I have reached a dead end.

I initialize TinyMCE with the following code:

```
tinymce.init({

selector: "textarea.editme",

plugins: ["advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor 
pagebreak spellchecker","searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code 
fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking","table contextmenu directionality 
emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor imageplugin"],

toolbar1: "image_list undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft 
aligncenter alignright alignjustify | fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor",

toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent 
blockquote | preview | table",

menubar: false,});
```

I don't have problems loading it so the code should be all right but I copied it here just in case.

I have a textarea with the right class "editme" to display TinyMCE. This text area is embedded in a form ()

I submit the form with the following code:

```
$("#submitform").submit(function(e)
{
tinyMCE.triggerSave(true,true);
var postData=$(this).serializeArray();
var url = 'php/forms_post.php'; 

$.ajax(
{
url : url,
type: "POST",
data : postData,
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
// DISPLAY SUCCESS
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
// DISPLAY FAILURE
}
});
e.preventDefault(); 
e.unbind(); 
});
```

The code works fine, except for one thing. If I write "aaaaaa" in the textarea the first time, it gets submitted correctly and everything is fine. But if I then change it to "bbbbbb", the data that is submitted is still "aaaaaa". It looks like the triggersave keeps the data in memory and refuses any changes. I already restarted the browser, the server, cleaned cache, cleaned cookies,... but still the problem is there.

If I remove TinyMCE and keep a standard textarea, I have no problem.

Do you have any idea of what's going wrong?

Thanks a lot
Laurent

Comment: is there a live example?

Comment: Unfortunately no, everything is on a local server not connected to the web.Do you know if there is anyway to check what is stored to force deletion of stored data?